# Tmux not using my Powerline characters

Tags: tmux, powerline

I have been trying to update tmux and add Powerline character support in it. I am currently using oh-my-zsh with 'agnoster' theme and powerline characters and prompt are getting displayed as they should but when i start tmux session, those character on prompt disappears and `_` is replaced with them.What can i do to rectify it.

[My tmux.conf](https://pastebin.com/M5HMZaDF)

- Using ubuntu 16.04
- Output of `echo $TERM` is `screen-256color`.
- Not using tmux-powerline as it's no longer maintained.
- I have also tried reinstalling Powerline.

Comment: Is there anything link i can look to?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `source "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf"` you should use `run 'powerline-config tmux setup'`, which should do all the automagic for you without explicily naming paths. You can give it a try by simply executing it in your shell after starting tmux.

Comment: after executing it in shell my status line has changed(like magic :D ) but prompt is still same and i have changed that line too and re run a source-file on `tmux.conf`

Comment: Are you on a utf-8 locale? Check `locale`

Comment: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`  
 `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: and now when i run `powerline-config tmux setup` in  shell, `unknown command` is displayed now

Comment: Well, then tmux does mess with your environment, doesn't it? Do you start tmux with `ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART`  and `ZSH_TMUX_AUTOCONNECT` in `.zshrc` ? That should work

Comment: I don't have these variable in zshrc, should i have it.